# extracting rows depending on the value of multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe that is simplified below. Given the following data frame structure, I need to collapse to return two distinct rows where col3 has different values but col1 and col2 have unique values.

```
dat <- data.frame("col1" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
       "col2" = c( "A","A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"," A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
       "col3" = c( "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"))

   col1 col2 col3
1     1    A    Z
2     1    A    Z
3     1    A    Z
4     1    A    Z
5     1    A    Z
6     1    A    Z
7     1    A    Z
8     1    A    Z
9     1    A    Z
10    1    A    Y
11    1    A    Y
12    1    A    Y
13    1    A    Y
14    1    A    Y
15    1    A    Y
```

So in this case I would need to return just the following:

```
   col1 col2 col3
      1    A    Z
      1    A    Y
```

If however, col3 was only z's I would return no rows. I can get counts of these data with the table function but I need to see the actual rows.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Well, I managed to get the desired output but I wonder if it work with your real data. I got it by using `as.data.frame(apply(dat, 2, unique))`. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Where do I see col1 = col2 in the example data? Do you mean for each unique combination of col1, col2 values?

Comment: @ Gopala, yes, that's what I mean. I apologize for the poor wording. I have updated to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  filter(length(unique(col3)) > 1) %>%
  distinct()
```

If `dat` is as follows:

```
dat <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), col2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), col3 = c("Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", 
"Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

You get no rows as follows:

```
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# Groups:   col1, col2 [0]
# ... with 3 variables: col1 <dbl>, col2 <chr>, col3 <chr>
```

If `dat` is as you provided in the original post, you get the output as you needed:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   col1, col2 [1]
   col1 col2  col3 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     Z    
2     1 A     Y
```

Notice that I am using `length(unique())` in the filter instead of `n_distinct` because there is a `dplyr` bug that makes `n_distinct` in a filter of a grouped data frame run extremely slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Nice easy `dplyr` solution:

```
dat <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), col2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), col3 = c("Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", 
"Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(col1,col2) %>% distinct()

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   col1, col2 [1]
   col1 col2  col3 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     Z    
2     1 A     Y
```

In your version of `dat` you have a space in one of your `col2` values, if that's not a typo, you'd need to fix that first so that `distinct()` aggregates correctly:

```
dat %>% mutate(col2 = trimws(col2)) %>% group_by(col1,col2) %>% distinct()
```

Comment: This won't work to produce 'no rows' output when col3 value is common throughout - as the poster suggests the output should be.